# Он все думал и думал, и наконец понял, в чем дело

Tags: пунктуация

Он все думал и думал(,) и наконец понял, в чем дело.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли эта запятая и по какому правилу

Answer (score 3):

***Он все думал и думал и наконец понял, в чем дело.***

Здесь нет выбора, **запятая не ставится.**

Первый союз ***И*** соединяет повторяющиеся формы глаголов ***думал***, а второй союз И соединяет эту пару и глагол ***понял***.

Если поставить запятую, то мы получим **перечислительную** интонацию и **однородные** отношения между тремя глагольными формами, а это не наш случай.

Здесь **смысл такой**: *Он долго думал и наконец понял, в чем дело.*

Тема разбирается у Розенталя  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом И, образуют **тесно связанную по смыслу пару**, соединенную союзом И с третьим однородным членом, **запятая не ставится:** Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам (Л. Т.)

Comment: Думаю, именно такой смысл автор и предполагал — _всё думал и думал._

Comment: Да, Римма, спасибо за понимание и поддержку.